# Javac can't find class that does exist in package

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I am new to java, and I am encountering an error that (after half an hour of searching) has not revealed itself. I have two classes (this is from me following a tutorial):

Board.java:

```
package skeleton;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel {
    public Board() {}
}
```

and Skeleton.java (I have stripped the non relevant material):

```
package skeleton;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Skeleton extends JFrame {
    public Skeleton() {
        add(new skeleton.Board());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Skeleton();
    }
}
```

I compile both of them, but Skeleton gets the error that it can't find Board. Does anyone know why javac can't find a class that is right there?

Edit: They are both in the same folder named 'skeleton'. Also, my OS is windows xp prof.

Comment: r u sure Board compiled?

Comment: Please provide the exact command that you tried to compile this with

Answer (score 1):

If its in the same package you don't need to use namespace to call the second class.

Try checking if `Board.class` file is present in the folder. The just use `new Board();` to instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

Gave it a try.

```
$ ls      
skeleton
$ ls skeleton
Board.java  Skeleton.java
$ javac skeleton/*.java
$ ls skeleton
Board.class  Board.java  Skeleton.class  Skeleton.java
```

Make invoke javac command such that both .class files land up in skeleton. Also, while running make sure parent directory of skeleton is in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you compiled and running in the same directory:

When running then use

```
java -cp . skeleton.Skeleton
```